# How to replace N repeated special characters in Bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace, opensuse

I want to replace any special character (not a number or letter) to one single '-'.

I tried the code below with some characters, but it doesn't work when the character is repeated more than 1 time because would still have more than one '-'.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f// /-}"; done

for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//_/-}"; done

for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//-/-}"; done
```

what I want:

```
test---file       ->  test-file

test   file       ->  test-file

test______file    ->  test-file

teeesst--ffile    ->  teeesst-ffile

test555----file__ ->  test555-file
```

Please, explain your answer because I don't know much about bash, regexp...

Comment: No loop needed. All you need is `tr -s [[:punct:]] '-'`, example: `echo "test______file" | tr -s [[:punct:]] '-'` Just paste that at the command line to test.

Comment: To handle the punctuation at the end, you can use a *command substitution*, e.g. `a=$(echo "test555----file__" | tr -s [[:punct:]] '-'); echo ${a%-}` yields `test555-file`

Comment: Two different file names can lead to the same file name. Be careful not to overwrite any files.

Comment: I'd go with something more beginner friendly 
`sed -e 's/\(\W\+\|\_\+\)\+/-/g' -e 's/-$//g'` 

sed is for stream editing. So you could pass a stream of file names into it. 

You seem to be asking to find *groups* of special character (not words and _) and change them into just one `-`.
Meaning in regex you are trying to find groupings of `\W` or `_` then you do not want any file to end in `-` so one more substitution `'s/-$//g'`

From here you could then write a small script to iterate over your files and then rename them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different `rename` (or `prename`) commands available in various distributions of Linux what will handle regex substitutions.

But you can also use Bash's extended globbing to do some of that. The pattern `${var//+([-_ ])/-}` says to replace any runs of one or more characters that are listed in the square brackets with one hyphen.

```
shopt -s extglob
# demonstration:
for file in test---file 'test   file' test______file teeesst--ffile test555----file__
do
    echo "${file//+([-_ ])/-}"
done
```

Output:

```
test-file
test-file
test-file
teeesst-ffile
test555-file-
```

The extended glob `+()` is similar to `.+` in regex. Other Bash extended globs (from `man bash`):

```
          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Note that the final hyphen is not removed here, but could be using an additional parameter expansion:

```
file=${file/%-/}
```

which says to remove a hyphen at the end of the string.

Comment: @JoãoVitorBarbosa: _**Always**_ quote variables when they are going to be expanded  and add `--` as the last option before the filename arguments just in case a filename might begin with a hyphen: `mv -n -- "${file[@]}" "${f//+([-_ ])/-}"`

Comment: thanks for the advice. It turns out to be a problem caused by looping over an array of filenames (some filenames had spaces). But just looping directly like :

for file in *.txt;  

solved.

Comment: @JoãoVitorBarbosa: Sorry I missed that one since it's hard to read code in comments. `for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$file"; done` Always quote your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` (as shown above in the comment) or, actually, `sed` makes more sense in this case. For example, given your list of filenames:

```
$ cat fnames
test---file
test   file
test______file
teeesst--ffile
test555----file__
```

You can use the `sed` expression:

```
sed -e 's/[[:punct:] ][[:punct:] ]*/-/' -e 's/[[:punct:] ]*$//'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -e 's/[[:punct:] ][[:punct:] ]*/-/' -e 's/[[:punct:] ]*$//' fnames
test-file
test-file
test-file
teeesst-ffile
test555-file
```

Depending on how your filenames are stored, you can either use *command substitution* individually, or you can use *process substitution* and feed the updated names into a `while` loop or something similar.